# Saving caffe Model C++ source code?

Tags: c++, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to save caffe net model to .caffemodel format using following code. But I am getting segmentation fault.

```
caffe::NetParameter net_param;
caffe_net_->ToProto(&net_param);
caffe::WriteProtoToBinaryFile(net_param, caffe_model_path);
```

where caffe_net_ is a trained caffe net, wgich containes blobs parameters.

Comment: `assert(caffe_net_)`?

Comment: Opps. I didn't see it's a year-old post. Not sure why it appeared at the top of my feed.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you would get a seg fault from that. That's exactly how you would manually save a network state. Have you tried stepping through and seeing at what point it faults? Otherwise, just snapshot it during training?

Comment: yes, I have debuged the program, and the problem occurs when the function "ToProto" get executed. Still I am unable to figure it out. It give be SIGSEGV error

Comment: @cybertrone I would recommend stepping within the ToProto method and determining where it failed.